# Difference of two metric tensors is no metric tensor

Tags: tensors

Are there other reasons that the difference of two (pseudo) metric tensors $g_{\mu\nu}-\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$ cannot be a metric apart from the fact that the non-degeneracy gets destroyed?

Comment: The statement is wrong. “Cannot” should be replaced with “may not.” Do you see why?

Comment: also, your choice of tag “metric spaces” is wrong here. This is a very common misconception, which I suggest you get straightened out (search on the site).

Comment: @TedShifrin for $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}=0$ it would be a metric.

Comment: @peek-a-boo sorry it changed automatically from metric to metric-spaces since the tag metric doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, I had less trivial examples in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A metric tensor is by definition  bilinear, symmetric and non-degenerate. The properties of bilinearity, symmetry and smoothness are preserved under taking linear combinations (i.e the set of bilinear symmetric tensor fields forms a real vector space). So, non-degeneracy is the only potential issue.

If you require smoothness (or any of the common regularity classes you like, e.g. analyticity or $C^k$, or Lipschitz or anything else) in your definition, that is also preserved under taking linear combinations, so that isn’t the issue.

Comment: Thank you I thought that too, but in a paper someone wrote that one cannot establish a geometrical meaning for the difference of two metrics. So I thought that it may destroy somehow the transformation properties of tensor but that isn‘t the case here, right?

Comment: nope not at all. without more context, I can’t tell what they might have intended instead.